# Apache Pig. Get one particular record

Tags: apache-pig

Given this 9 record file:

```
START-OF-FIELDS
FUND_TAX_STATUS
EQY_SH_OUT
FUND_REDEMP_DT
FUND_MIN_INVEST_CRNCY
ID_EXCH_SYMBOL
FUNDSERV_IDENTIFIER
TIMESTARTED=Wed Apr 13 02:01:27 JST 2016
START-OF-DATA
```

I would like to get just the `TIMESTARTED` record.

How can I achieve that?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load the records as one field of datatype chararray and filter it.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') as (f1:chararray);
B = FILTER A BY (f1 matches '.*TIMESTARTED.*');
DUMP B;
```